# Possible bug in fetching price index data?

Tags: curated-data, finance

I seem only able to fetch price index data for the U.S.  For example, the following fails (*Mathematica* 10.2):

```
Entity["Country", "France"][
  EntityProperty["Country", "PriceIndex", {"Date" -> 2008}]]
```

Use of `CountryData` also fails. Is there another way to access this data?

Comment: It's interesting that, no matter what country one specifies, your command returns an unevaluated call to `CalculateUtilities\`DataPaclets\`CalculateUSEconomicData\`CalculateUSEconomicData`. The "US" part in the name of those functions is ominous... I'd report to WRI, at least for clarification.

Comment: `CountryData["France", {{"PriceIndex"}, 2008}]` returns `165.428` in Mma v10.2 Win7 64

Comment: @rhermans Confirmed.  It is only aft 2008 that the data are missing using `CountryData`.

Comment: @rhermans recommendation can be extended to the period 1970-2008 with `CountryData["France", {{"PriceIndex"}, All}]`.